# What is 照拂 in 我是你照拂的梦?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, phrase-meaning

So in this line 我是你照拂的梦, both Google and Apple have translated as I am your dream.  What about 照拂?  What does 照拂 describe 梦 or 你?

Comment: Which dictionaries have you consulted? I count 14 dictionaries that have included this word in Pleco, not counting Wiktionary which is likely to also contain this word.

Comment: On a literal level, it kinda means care. Where did you see this sentence? Providing some context may allow me to help with the translation

Comment: 照拂 means 照顾、照料. More context is required to make a good/precise translation, as It does not make sense in the lone sentence (from a lyric) provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the first definition in [照拂](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%85%A7%E6%8B%82). It means 照顾 (look after).

I assume that this line is from the lyrics of [如愿](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%A6%82%E6%84%BF/58650077), the promotion song of [My Country, My Parents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Country,_My_Parents). Here I also translate the previous line to explain my understanding.

- 你是明月清风 (You are the bright moon and the fresh breeze)
- 我是你**照拂**的梦 (I am the dream that you **cherish** (**look after**))

Basically it means that you (parent) look after me. Note that the moon can 照 (照亮) and the breeze can 拂 (吹拂). So given the context, it'd be better (hopefully more poetic) to translate it as

- I am the dream that you **light upon and kiss**

which is close to the second definition, 映照煦拂.

---

#### Update

As Wayne Cheah said in the comment, it's weird to "look after" a dream. So I adopt the suggestion and use "cherish" in the sentence now :)

Comment: "look after", what an excellent interpretation of 照拂.

Comment: I think for "subjects" like "dreams", which are emotional experiences and thus non-physical in nature, a literal, dictionary translation like "look after" do not seem appropriate. Perhaps "cherish", (which also involves the element of "caring for") is a better term for a substantive translation?

Comment: @WayneCheah Yes. I know it's weird to "look after" a dream, but I just couldn't come up with a better word from my poor vocabulary... Thank you for providing "cherish" as an alternative. Just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

as a native speaker with a bachelor degree, I really don't know what this sentence is talking about,this is the first time I encounter the word "照拂".
some chinese songwriter always want to impress others and add too many strange words to their song,making their line hard to read.
you can just omit this sentence,learning this kind of sentence don't help development in your Chinese learning at all.